# Is it good to use default tablespace for high volume tables?

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, oracle12c, tablespace

In our application (Oracle based) we are handling high volume of data. For few major tables, we are using separate tablespace but for the remaining tables default tablespace is being used.

My query is,

a. Is it good (In terms of performance) to have separate tablespace for every table (where the number of records are more than million)
b. Or we can define a separate tablespace instead of default table space for the remaining tables. 
c. Does it affect the performance if default tablespace is used for the high volume tables?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SANs seem to have killed this debate, however, when you consider things like locally managed tablespaces, there is a trend to use these to get tables to inherit storage properties. For example, it is very common these days to see tablepsaces like LM_SMALL_TABLE, LM_MEDIUM_TABLE, LM_LARGE_TABLE (and similar for index), or LM_16k_TABLE, LM_1M_TABLE, LM_10M_TABLE, LM_100M_TABLE and similar for indexes. These will have initial and next extents set to 16k, 1m, etc. Tables are then placed in the tablespace that is appropriate to expected volume. You sometimes see database where there is archived/read-only data moved to cheaper disk by moving the table/partition to such tablespaces. The only time I've seen 1 tablespace per table was on 8i, where the client wanted had this so that a particular table could be restored to a backup, by restoring just the tablespace/datafiles.

Comment: I would not call that "very common".  A large number of tablespaces is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Usually nowadays you don't have dedicated disc for your tablespaces, data are stored in a storage network (SAN) and you don't have any fixed relation to a physical file system. Thus the distribution of tablespaces is less sensitive or critical as in earlier day - as long as you don't have **very special** or **very big** data.

For example I have an application where I get every day about 1 billion records, i.e app. 150GB. There I use one tablespace (i.e. 150 cycling tablespaces) for each daily partition. The main reason is easier maintenance, for example truncating old data.